# Why the test case failing for Roy and profile picture hackerearth?

Tags: java

Problem: Roy wants to change his profile picture on Facebook. Now Facebook has some restriction over the dimension of picture that we can upload.
Minimum dimension of the picture can be L x L, where L is the length of the side of square.

Now Roy has N photos of various dimensions.
Dimension of a photo is denoted as W x H
where W - width of the photo and H - Height of the photo

When any photo is uploaded following events may occur:

1. If any of the width or height is less than L, user is prompted to upload another one. Print "UPLOAD ANOTHER" in this case.
2. If width and height, both are large enough and

   - if the photo is already square then it is accepted. Print "ACCEPTED" in this case.
   - else user is prompted to crop it. Print "CROP IT" in this case.

(quotes are only for clarification)

Given L, N, W and H as input, print appropriate text as output.

Input:
First line contains L.
Second line contains N, number of photos.
Following N lines each contains two space separated integers W and H.

Output:
Print appropriate text for each photo in a new line.

Constraints:

```
1 <= L,W,H <= 10000
1 <= N <= 1000
```

Java Program:

```
package com.chef.code;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FacebookProfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int length = sc.nextInt();

        int nphotos = sc.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        ArrayList<Integer> y = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nphotos; i++) {

            x.add(sc.nextInt());
            y.add(sc.nextInt());

        }

        for (int j = 0; j < nphotos; j++) {

            if (length == x.get(j) || x.get(j) == y.get(j)) {
                System.out.println("ACCEPTED");
            }

            else if (length < x.get(j) ) {
                System.out.println("CROP IT");
            }

            else if (length > x.get(j))  {
                System.out.println("UPLOAD ANOTHER");
            }


    }
    }

}
```

Test Case:

```
180
5
640 480
120 300
180 180
**400 400**
200 180
```

I'm trying to execute but the code is failing for test case (400,400).

Not sure, why the control is not getting through the if block:

```
  if (length == x.get(j) || x.get(j) == y.get(j)) {

   System.out.println("ACCEPTED");

  }
```

Here

```
length = 180

x.get(j) = 400

y.get(j) = 400
```

As per the OR logic if one of the condition is true it should print ACCEPTED.

Comment: One of the problems with your code (that is also present in the answer of user7) is `x.get(j) == y.get(j)` - `x` and `y` are `ArrayList<Integer>` and that means that `x.get(j) == y.get(j)` compares two `Integer` objects. You must replace it with `x.get(j).equals(y.get(j))`

Answer (score 1):

`x.get(j) == y.get(j)` compares two Integer objects.

You **must** replace it with `x.get(j).equals(y.get(j))`.

This is because `x.get(j)` doesn't return the int value `400` - it returns `Integer.valueOf(400)`. `Integer.valueOf()` caches some the `Integer` objects (for values in the range from -128 to +127), for all other values it returns new `Integer` objects on each call. And that means that `System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(400) == Integer.valueOf(400));` prints "false" - always.

The correct way to compare `Integer` objects is the same as for comparing other objects: use the `equals()` method.

`System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(400).equals(Integer.valueOf(400)));` will print "true".

---

To be honest I also don't understand why you first read the whole input into two `ArrayList<Integer>`s and do the work afterwards - you could easily implement the logic in a single pass:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nphotos; i++) {

    int x = sc.nextInt();
    int y = sc.nextInt();

    if (length == x || x == y) {
        // [...]
    }
}
```

and drop the second loop.

Answer (score -2):

thanks for the quick response. Keeping the logic aside.

```
if (length == x.get(j) || x.get(j) == y.get(j)) {

System.out.println("ACCEPTED");

}
```

Why the control ain’t entering the if block when the condition

`x.get(j) == y.get(j)` is satisfied?

Here length = 180

x.get(j) = 400

y.get(j) = 400

Could you please let me know how it works ?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, it should be part of your question (you can edit your question be clicking on the "Edit" link below it).